# passwordless sudo for nginx restart not working

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, sudo

Went into my sudoers file and added this to the bottom:

```
tristan ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/service nginx start,/usr/sbin/service nginx stop,/usr/sbin/service nginx restart
```

Now in command line when I just write `service nginx stop` I get `Stopping nginx:` but not actually stopping... only when I do `sudo service nginx stop` it works.

Do I have to restart ubuntu that's why or what's happening?

Should also mention above in my sudoers file is:

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
tristan ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all: If you set a NOPASSWD: in a sudo, you still have to type "sudo service ...." to perform as root. It only changes the behaviour, that you don't need to enter your own password when sudo-ing. There is no "auto-sudo", you have to create a specialized init script if you really need that. Or try to set an alias.

Second, if you configure a sudo to /usr/sbin/service nginx ... then you must type sudo /usr/sbin/service nginx ... to match that, typing service nginx ... (without path) it will fall through to "tristan ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL".

Try a "sudo -l", to see which sudo permissions you have.

rgds,
j.